# javaScript dynamic programming

Tags: javascript, dynamic-programming

I am learning how to use memoization and I have this problem

```js
const memo = {
  0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 1
};

function tribonacci(n, memo) {
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE NEXT FOUR LINES
  if (n in memo) return memo[n];
  const n1 = tribonacci(n - 1)
  const n2 = tribonacci(n - 2)
  const n3 = tribonacci(n - 3)
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE PREVIOUS FOUR LINES

  // Your code here
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) return 1;
  memo[n] = n1 + n2 + n3;
  return memo[n];
}

console.log(tribonacci(3));
```

But it gives me 2 errors. It says "cannot use in operator of 3 in undefined" and "cannot use in operator to search for 30 in undefined" and I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Why is `memo` a parameter?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the parameters used to produce the error messages you are using.

Comment: Only way to fix the bug would be to change the lines that say not to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the parameter in the function definition.

```js
const memo = {
  0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 1
};

function tribonacci(n) {
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE NEXT FOUR LINES
  if (n in memo) return memo[n];
  const n1 = tribonacci(n - 1)
  const n2 = tribonacci(n - 2)
  const n3 = tribonacci(n - 3)
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE PREVIOUS FOUR LINES

  // Your code here
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) return 1;
  memo[n] = n1 + n2 + n3;
  return memo[n];
}

console.log(tribonacci(3));
```

And here is the complete version to compute the Fibonacci list.

```js
const memo = {
  0: 0,
  1: 0,
  2: 1
};

function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n in memo) return memo[n];
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) return 1
  memo[n] = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
  return memo[n]
}

console.log(fibonacci(10));
console.log(memo)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues with your code:

1. You created a local parameter `memo` which is always `undefined` (unless you pass it in as an argument to your function call), and overshadows your file-scope `memo` variable. Simply removing that will fix the error you reported.
2. Your terminal case usually must be at the beginning of your recursion. Else you will get an infinite loop. Move the second `if` up to before calling `tribonacci` again.

There might be more issues, but these are certainly two big ones.

Answer (score 0):

So I have refactor this a little bit and it now looks like this, but it is not passing again and it says the tribonacci is not a function

```
// const memo = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1};
function tribonacci(n, memo = {}) {
  if (n in memo) return memo[n];
  if (n === 1 || n === 2) return 1;
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE NEXT FOUR LINES
  const n1 = tribonacci(n - 1);
  const n2 = tribonacci(n - 2);
  const n3 = tribonacci(n - 3);
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE PREVIOUS FOUR LINES

  // Your code here
  memo[n] = (n1, memo) + (n2, memo) + (n3, memo);
  return memo[n];
}
```

I am sure they probably want me to use the memo object I commented out but Im unsure

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```js
function tribonacci(n = 0, memo = {}) {
  if (memo[n]) return memo[n];
  if (n < 2) return 1;

  const $n1 = n - 1;
  const $n2 = n - 2;
  const $n3 = n - 3;

  const n1 = memo[$n1] || tribonacci($n1, memo)
  const n2 = memo[$n2] || tribonacci($n2, memo)
  const n3 = memo[$n3] || tribonacci($n3, memo)

  memo[n] = n1 + n2 + n3;

  return memo[n];
}

console.log(tribonacci(3));
```